# Tooltip of highchart is not displaying properly

Tags: highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I am trying to generate column chart of highcharts using rchart library. Spline and pie chart worked me fine. But column chart's tooltip is not rendering properly 
[image]

I am using following code to generate it

```
res <- getForumNumDiscussionsData()
h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$chart(type = "column")


res <- getForumNumDiscussionsData()
h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$chart(type = "column")

#axis
h1$xAxis(title=list(text="Number of Discussions"),categories=res$categories)
h1$yAxis(title=list(text="Number of students"))

#plot options
h1$plotOptions(column=list(pointPadding=0,borderWidth=0))

#series
h1$series(data = res$count,name="students")


#export
h1$exporting(sourceWidth = 1000, sourceHeight = 400)
```

and data frame : res

```
  categories  count

1   < 13     12 
2   < 24     121
3   < 39     13
```

Can anybody help me to render tooltip text properly

Comment: its because I have categories for xAxis a set of strings.

Comment: Have you tried to set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML) flag as true?

Comment: Actually, if you see categories column in data frame, there "less than" symbol. I forgot to use &lt; instead of "<".